Integrated Gradients implementation for 2D input in PyTorch
I am trying to implement the Integrated Gradient calculation (described in this article) for a GNN I am working with. Specifically, I am using Eq3 from the paper
My input for the network is a NxM matrix representing a graph of N vertices, each one with a feature vector of M dimensions.
How to extend the method in the paper, considering that they derive it for an input of N dimensions, and in my case I'd like to get a single score for each one of the nodes?
In my current implementation I obtain a matrix of NxM which I collapse by doing torch.sum(dim=1), however this doesn't feel as clean as it could be
This is my current implementation in PyTorch
graph_copy = input_graph.detach().clone()
# k/m in the formula
k_m = torch.linspace(0, 1, n_steps)
# Array to store the samples
input_features = [baseline.clone()]    # The first sample is the baseline
# x-x'
diff = original_input_feature - baseline

# Populates the samples array
for i in range(1, k_m.shape[0]):
    temp = baseline + k_m[i] * diff
    input_features_path.append(temp)

gradients = []
for i in range(k_m.shape[0]):
    ### Zeroing the gradient of the vectors for each input 
    input_features[i].requires_grad = True
    model.zero_grad()
    task.zero_grad()
    
    temp_model_out = model(graph = graph_copy, input = input_features[i])['graph_feature'][0]
    temp_mlp_output = task.mlp(temp_model_out)
    temp_prob = Softmax(temp_mlp_output, dim = 0)

    temp_gradient = grad(outputs = temp_prob[true_label_id], inputs = input_features_path[i])
    gradients.append(temp_gradient[0])

    input_features_path[i].requires_grad = False

with torch.no_grad():
    ig_scores = original_input_feature * torch.stack(gradients, dim = 2).mean(dim = 2)    
    final_ig_scores = ig_scores.sum(dim = 1)
    sorted, indices = torch.sort(final_ig_scores, descending = True)



what do you mean by "clean"? The torch.sum(dim=1) part is totally ok. If you want to get an answer, you have to atleast give us a minimum reproducible example and more clear abour the reason.

By "clean" I was implying that I have no justification to do torch.sum(dim=1) besides that I get a tensor with the right dimensions. I am concerned that by simply adding the scores along the rows I can be making a mistake, and understimating the attribution scores simply because the IG values can also be negative. I thought about taking the 2-D norm as torch.norm(ig_scores, dim=1) but I have no stronger arguments besides what I described above.
I am working with protein graphs and it can be hard to provide a working example in here, but I'll try to set something up and share it

Can you provide me with an minimum reproducible example, like the model, sample data shape, and/or training pass
